# How can I get CodeRush to fix my typing? ( {Get; set;} to {get; set;} ) (spellcheck/capscheck)

Tags: coderush

My most common issue is the caps is still on when I get to Get in a property setter.

I know ReSharper does this, but, doesn't CodeRush?
When I type:

```
public int Count {Get; set;}
```

I want

```
public int Count {get; set;}
```

Where does one change this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I'm unable to replicate your initial issue. It seems that my copy of studio automatically corrects this in exactly the way you suggest.

However, in case there is some strange quirk at work for me which is failing to work for you, there is a relatively simple Coderush feature which might help you in this area.

When you wish to declare an autoproperty (as seems to be the case here) simple type:

```
    ai<space>
```

Coderush will use a template (upgraded version of snippets) to create the following scenario for you.

[image: AutoPropertyTemplate]

From here you simply overtype the default property name of 'PropertyName' with your identifier 'Count' and then hit 'Enter ' twice.

You should now be positioned to create more properties or otherwise continue your code without ever having needed to manually express the boilerplate code.

Side Note: There is a pattern to the characters you type in this template.
The 'a' stands for AutoProperty and invokes this particular template. Other options include:

```
p - Property 
r - Readonly property
v - Variable
m - Method
```

Capitalizing any of these will make them static.

THe 'i' stands for integer and can be replaced with many alternatives including

```
s - string
b - bool
d - decimal
d8 - date

/ - Name of class you are within
\ - value you have on the clipboard.
```

And finally you can mix these up in any combination you like.

```
mi - Method returning integer
pb - Property of type boolean
vd.s,d8 - Variable of type Dictionary<string, date>
```

I do appreciate this isn't exactly what you asked for, but perhaps it will be of help in the situation you face.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Rory's answer, you can learn more about the CodeRush templates for declaring properties here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olpK5oDWYwY&list=PL8h4jt35t1wgawacCN9wmxq1EN36CNUGk&index=10

And the feature of the week series is here:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8h4jt35t1wgawacCN9wmxq1EN36CNUGk